# JTable setModel cant acces to instance variables

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i have a big problem with setModel to jTable in swing.
I have good sql connection, works fine.

This is constructor of JFrame:

```
public class MainPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private String selectedId;
private DBConn db;
public Vector<String> header;
public Vector<Vector<String>> data;


/**
 * Creates new form MainPanel
 */
public MainPanel() {

    db = new DBConn();

    selectedId = "nothing";
    Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>();
    Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>(db.allFilms()); 
    header.add("ID");
    header.add("Name");
    header.add("Genre");
    header.add("Rating");

    System.out.println(header.get(1)); // this works ok
    System.out.println(data.get(1)); //this works ok too
    initComponents();
}
```

and then i have function initComponents

```
private void initComponents() {

    jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jMenu3.setText("jMenu3");

    jMenu4.setText("jMenu4");

    jMenu1.setText("jMenu1");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    System.out.println(header.get(1)); // this crashed
    jTable2.setFocusable(false);
    jTable2.setOpaque(false);
    jTable2.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        this.data, this.header
    ));
    jTable2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jTable2MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
```

But when i'm in function initComponents and i want to get data from data or header, the exception throws `(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException)`

So i cant use setModel. Thanks for any answer.

Comment: no idea for why reason is there this.data, this.header, this is local variables, isn't reason for..., sure nobody know whats returns (db.allFilms());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code I can see you are creating local instances of your variables in the constructor:

```
 Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>();
 Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>(db.allFilms());
```

While you have to initialize your instance variables, so no need of declaring again:

```
this.header = new Vector<String>();
this.data = new Vector<Vector<String>>(db.allFilms());
```

If you create new variables and assign values to them, your instance variables remain empty that's why you are getting a null pointer exception. Best regards.

Comment: No problem colleague, sometimes it happens to all of us, so don't worry, pleased to help you, best regards (:

Answer (score -1):

Try this.data=... and this.header=... in the constructor. The way you did it, you are just initializing local variables, so your class variables remain null.